# How to rearrange KendoGrid Tab Order?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, grid, kendo-ui

I'm using a KendoGrid and doing a inline batch edit. Only a select few columns are editable. When hit tab the next column selected but it is not the next editable column. Is there a way to control the tab order in a KendoGrid? How would I make the tabs skip columns that are not editable?

My Mark-UP:

```
<div id="employeeGoalsGrid"></div>
```

My Javascript:

```
var goalsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/MVC/ResearcherPoints/GetEmployeeResearchers',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            },
            update: {
                url: '/MVC/ResearcherPoints/UpdateEmployeeGoal',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json'
                //dataType: "jsonp"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                debugger;
                $.extend(options, { ID: options.id });
                return JSON.stringify(options);
            }
        },
        batch: false,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: 'ID',
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                    FirstName: { editable: false, nullable: true  },
                    LastName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    Title: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    TeamName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    PointsGoal: { type: "number", nullable: true, validation: { required: false, min: 1 } }
                }
            }
        },
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        columnMenu: true
    });


    $('#employeeGoalsGrid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: goalsDataSource,
        navigatable: true,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
        columns: [
            { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: 200},
            { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: 200 },
            { field: "Title", title: "Title", width: 200 },
            { field: "TeamName", title: "Team", width: 200 },
            { field: "PointsGoal", title: "Goal", width: 200 }],
        editable: true,
        filterable: true,
    });
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the problem that navigation selects all columns on your grid although `editable` works fine?

Comment: Yes. When I hit tab, the focus moves to the next column just fine but I want to skip the non-editable columns and jump to the next editable column.

Comment: Can you post a sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)? I'd love to help, but it would be great to be able to start from an interactive sample.

Answer (score 3):

To skip cell you need to use [`tabindex="99999"`](http://jehiah.cz/a/tabindex)

I created a jsfiddle for testing purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/danieltulp/kfG7y/

I think you need to look at using attributes: { tabindex: "999999" } in

```
{ field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110,  attributes: { tabindex: "999999" } }
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Anyone a better idea?

Perhaps this just isn't possible?

Comment: +1 Thanks for putting your jsFiddle on your answer. -1 for not giving me an answer. +1 because I'm glad that I'm not the only one with this problem. This is still unsolved for me. I would love for Kendo to fix this issue. (Sorry I can only give you +1)

Comment: Its not my code.  Just the demo from the kendo website. Created it to try to solve it for you but faild. Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the `editable` property on the grid options from `true` to `"inline"` and let me know if that fixes the issue? I've created a similar scenario in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iyozez/1/) and the tab order works fine (Chrome on OSX) when I edit a row.

Comment: I'm doing a batch edit. I really only a single column that is editable. I need to just jump down a row when the tab is hit. By changing this to inline. The user now has to click save on each row.